# recursively finding arithmetic mean of vector

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

Just an academic exercise but it doesn't work with many inputs for some unknown reason.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

double sum (const vector<double>&, size_t = 0);

int main () {
  vector<double> in;
  double temp{0};
  while (cin >> temp)
    in.push_back(temp);
  cout << sum(in) << endl;
  return 0;
}

double sum (const vector<double>& v, size_t it) {
  if (it + 1 >= v.size())
    return v.at(it)/v.size();
  return v.at(it)/v.size() + sum(v,it+1);
}
```

a few dozen numbers and it works just fine, but once I import a text file with every positive integer from 1 to 100000 as the input (in windows cmd) it takes a few seconds and then just terminates the programme but without any output.

compiler: g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

Comment: Sounds like a stack overflow

Comment: Note that `it == v.size() - 1` won't do what you want if your vector is empty. Better to check `it + 1 >= v.size()`.

Comment: @scohe001 my bad, corrected it

Comment: Code-Apprentice is correct: `it takes a few seconds and then just terminates the programme but without any output.` - this indeed sounds like "infinite recursion".  SUGGESTIONS: 1) step through the code under the debugger (*ALWAYS* step through the code in a debugger *FIRST*!)  2) Look at scohe001's suggestion regarding ".size()"

Comment: Alternative suggestion: flip the logic and test `if (it < v.size())`

Comment: @user4581301 doesn't make a difference

Comment: Maybe I didn't do an authentic reproduction but I [tried to reproduce this](https://godbolt.org/z/5ahdGf) on godbolt and didn't get the described problem

Comment: Why not just compute a running sum. But I think recursing 100,000 levels deep might be a problem.

Comment: Side note: floating point numbers are inherently imprecise. You may find you get better results by summing and then dividing the sum at the end.

Comment: @user4581301: that has its own issues w/ overflow. In reality it's a difficult problem to do properly, which is why you should lean on a library like [Boost accumulators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/accumulators.html)

Comment: @Ruzihm weirdly enough, I copied your code from compiler explorer and it produces the same problem on my machine

Comment: @user4581301 I tried that as well, same resut, I'm particularly interested as to why it doesn't work with doubles

Comment: @AndyG thanks for the tip, this caps off at 32501 positive integers (implicitly converted to doubles) for some reason... anything past 32501 inputs it can't handle

Comment: The problem is, as many have already stated, 100000 recursive iteration is almost certainly running the program out of automatic storage (and probably causing a stack overflow) If the only overhead is a 64 bit `size_t` on the stack,  the program has consumed 800,000 bytes of the 1 MB Windows default stack. If there is any other overhead, the program will certainly misbehave (and that includes dying).

Comment: @Biaaach: That sounds... like a strange limitation. I see no such limit [here](https://godbolt.org/z/75dj5n)

Comment: 32501 looks like the program is eating around 32 bytes of stack every call. Or maybe it overflowed much earlier and 32501 is where the CPU finally noticed the program had gone off into the weeds and killed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running out of stack due to the deep recursion.

If you rewrite to be tail-recursive, gcc will replace the recursive calls with jumps if you enable any optimization, and only use constant space:

```
double sum_t (const vector<double>& v, size_t it, double acc) {
  if (it + 1 >= v.size())
      return acc;
  return sum_t(v, it+1, acc + v.at(it)/v.size());
}

double sum (const vector<double>& v, size_t it) {
    return sum_t(v, it, 0.0);
}
```

Comment: If the OP was using gdb... then he'd have a stack track - and it would be *OBVIOUS* that a) the problem was infinite recursion, b) the OP could see how *DEEPLY* he recursed (32501?) before the crash and c) he could evaluate his parameters (`v` and `it`) at the point of failure.  I'm harping on the issue ... sometimes developers would rather have a root canal than learn the debugger...  Which is very unfortunate...

Comment: @modlbdnilo thanks for suggesting an alternative:  using an explicit stack i.e. assigning the intermediary results to a preallocated space deifinitely solves the problem... I don't see what tail-recursion has to do with it tho unless I'm using tail-call optimisation

Comment: @paulsm4 yep, that's the takeaway from this thread

Comment: @Biaaach I did not suggest that alternative (which also suffers from the need to preallocate enough space) and it's not a very good one - a plain iterative loop is better. gcc will optimise tail calls into jumps when it can, like in this case.